# How to make Windows Explorer release focus on a file without the mouse?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, ergonomics

I always try to use my computer without touching the mouse and keep both hands on the keyboard at all time. It really boosts my productivity because I do not need to move my hand over to the mouse for common tasks. However, I've come accross a case where I cannot manage to do it with the keyboard only.

When navigating through Windows Explorer, say I have the focus on a file, but I want to open up the context menu as if no file is selected, like when you want to create a new folder or any other action not related to the file per se. What I currently do is move my hand to the mouse, and right-click to make that menu pop.

How would I achieve this without using the mouse?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> as the icon is selected

Comment: To create the new folder after removing focus from the file you selected, use ctrl+shift+N

Comment: No need to deselect the item before ctrl+shift+N